# How to query from two database servers

Tags: t-sql

There are two identical Databases present on two different servers. Each of the two Databases have similar information, but from different companies. I am trying to get the information from both the Databases, somthing similar to this. I dont have permission to create a linked server.

Any suggestions? ( I am using T-SQL)

```
select A,B,C
from server1.Database1.dbo.table1

UNION ALL

select A,B,C
from server2.Database2.dbo.table1
```

Comment: Hi there. I am actually finishing up a program to do exactly this (and more) and could use some help testing. While the end goal is that a fully functional version will require purchase, a Free version will definitely be available and for what you need, the Free version will suffice. If you are interested, please go to the website shown in my profile and contact me from there.

Comment: @srutzky - I am waiting to see if the DBA will give me permission to create linkd server. IF not, I will definitely try out your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Linked Server is best, IMO, if you can manage it.

In cases where our DBA won't allow that, I'll often use a client-installed database (like MS Access), and link to the tables in both servers, and then write my query there.